# Contest Problem - Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of 
>   $$\dfrac{\cos30.5 + \cos31.5+\cdots + \cos44.5}{\sin30.5 + \sin31.5+\cdots + \sin44.5}$$

This came from HMMT 2018 Problem no 17.  Could someone explain to me the solution with a diagram.  I solved it in a different way.

https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2018/feb/guts/solutions.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each sum is telescopic! Show that
$$\cos(0.5+k)=\frac{\sin(k+1)-\sin(k)}{2\sin(0.5)}
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\sin(0.5+k)=\frac{\cos(k)-\cos(k+1)}{2\sin(0.5)}.$$
Therefore at the numerator we have
$$\cos(30.5) + \cos(31.5)+\cdots + \cos(44.5)=\frac{\sin(45)-\sin(30)}{2\sin(0.5)}.$$
In a similar way at the denominator we find
$$\sin(30.5) + \sin(31.5)+\cdots + \sin(44.5)
=\frac{\cos(30)-\cos(45)}{2\sin(0.5)}.$$